# angular2-google-maps read apikey from web.config

Tags: google-maps, angular

We intergrated angular2-google-maps in our project. The project is built angularjs 2 release version and using webapi.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig, AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

import { appConfig,IAppConfig,GoogleMapApiKey } from "./app.config";

@NgModule({
    imports: [

        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: ""
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent      

    ],
    providers: [       

        { provide: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfig, useValue: GoogleMapApiKey } 
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.config.ts**

```
import { OpaqueToken } from "@angular/core";

export let appConfig = new OpaqueToken('app.config');

export interface IAppConfig {
    apiKey: string
}

export const GoogleMapApiKey : IAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "Key"
};
```

I hardcoded the google map api key in the typescript file. Is it possible to read it from .net web.config file.

Also is this correct way of displaying the map or can i make it part of component.

Any suggestions.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but - did you find the solution?

Comment: we used gulp to read the property